TypeScript polymorphic this type in interfaces
is it possible to emulate TypeScript's polymorphic this type behaviour using just interfaces instead of classes? Suppose I have some code like this:
interface Foo {
  foo(): this;
}

interface Bar extends Foo {
  bar(): this;
}

function foo(this: Foo) { return this; }
function bar(this: Bar) { return this; }

function newFoo(): Foo {
  return { foo };
}

function newBar(): Bar {
  return { ...newFoo(), bar }; // Property 'bar' is missing in type 'Foo' but required in type 'Bar'.
}

The newBar() constructor doesn't type check, since the returntype of the foo() coming from destructured newFoo() is inferred as Foo instead of Bar.
I found that the reverse method of wrapping mixins works:
function fooish<T>(object: T): T & Foo {
  return { ...object, foo };
}

function newBar2(): Bar {
  return fooish({ bar }); // Typechecks fine
}

However, there are some situations where I would much prefer the first method, i.e. have a simple constructor which just returns Foo instead of T & Foo and compose by spreading properties, not by application. Essentially what I'm looking for is inheritance with interfaces, such that this remains typed correctly.
Any ideas?

I don't get it. newFoo returns Foo, not this. Inside a Bar you need the foo() method to return a Bar and not a Foo, since this is now Bar. I'm confused about what you're trying to achieve and how what you're doing is supposed to be type safe. Where specifically are you trying to "emulate" the this type? I mean, you're using this in your code, so presumably it's actually supposed to use the type and not emulate it. I'm hopelessly confused here. Could you please [edit] to clarify?

Sorry if I wasn't clear. If I have a class Foo with a method foo that returns the instance of Foo back i.e. return this, and if I subclass it as Bar extends Foo, then the method foo on Bar will have returntype Bar (instead of Foo). I'd like to do something like that with interfaces. Not sure how to phrase that in an edit.

• Presumably you're saying you want foo() and bar() to return this then. It's not the interfaces that need something special (since interfaces support this just fine), it's the standalone functions you're using as methods. I would appreciate if you could [edit] to say that, but if you can't figure out how, I might do my own edit after a while. • Possibly this approach might work, where you use generics to handle the necessary polymorphism (this is implemented as an implicit generic type). If so I'll write an answer; if not, what's missing?

I'm probably missing something but I don't see how it's a problem with the functions, e.g. function newBar() { return { ...({} as Foo), bar }; }; shows the same error.

Oh yeah, in the playground example the inference works well, I might be using an older version of TypeScript, will try updating & see if that helps.

In order for {...({} as Foo), bar} to be a Bar, that as Foo would have to be an as Pick<Bar, "foo">.  The foo part of a Foo isn't required to be appropriate to a Bar. Maybe you're confused about how polymorphic this works or what it means? The only possible way your code could be type safe is if the foo() method is known to return this for the current this. It isn't that Foo.foo returns Foo and Bar.bar returns Bar.

Okok, I see, thank you for your time @jcalz, brilliant as always. Your answer works well, it's a bit annoying that I have to prefix every method that returns this with generic but I guess it makes sense. Feel free to write up the answer and I will approve it.

I will do so when I get a chance.

Probably going to be a number of hours from now at the earliest.

The polymorphic this type is implicitly generic. The this type is a special type of F-bounded polymorphism called "the curiously recurring template pattern in C++. For a type implementer, this is "some generic subtype of the current type I'm writing" whereas for a type user, this is that type.  If you want to implement Foo, you need to make sure that the foo() method returns whatever subtype of Foo is being used later.
Your code is essentially equivalent to
interface Foo<T extends Foo<T>> {
  foo(): T;
}
interface PlainFoo extends Foo<PlainFoo> {}

interface Bar<T extends Bar<T>> extends Foo<T> {
  bar(): T;
}
interface PlainBar extends Bar<PlainBar> {}

function foo(this: PlainFoo) { return this; }
function bar(this: PlainBar) { return this; }

function newFoo(): PlainFoo {
  return { foo };
}

function newBar(): PlainBar {
  return { ...newFoo(), bar }; 
  // Property 'bar' is missing in type 'Foo<PlainFoo>' 
  // but required in type 'Bar<PlainBar>'
}

where now it's hopefully clear what the problem is. Your newBar() purports to return a PlainBar, but that is a Bar<PlainBar>, which is a Foo<PlainBar>, and therefore the foo() method needs to return a PlainBar. But instead it returns a PlainFoo.  The this type needs to get narrower in subclasses, that's the whole point.

So, in order for your code to work with
interface Foo { foo(): this; }
interface Bar extends Foo { bar(): this; }

You need foo and bar to return this, not Foo and Bar. That means the generic of this needs to be represented as a generic type parameter explicitly:
function foo<T extends Foo>(this: T) { return this; }
function bar<T extends Bar>(this: T) { return this; }

And now things work (and you don't want to annotate newFoo()'s return type as Foo either, since that clobbers the generic:
function newFoo() {
  return { foo };
}

function newBar(): Bar {
  return { ...newFoo(), bar };
}

All this works now, because the polymorphic nature of this is maintained.
Playground link to code
